# How to pass parameter to another controller and open new page in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project info page, I need to generate a report upon user selected project number and date.
How can I open a report page(say from `noisedevice/report.html.erb`) from project info view( `project/report.html.erb`)?

I feel need to pass parameter from view page to another controller(noisedevice's controller)then call some function(or router??) to generate a new report page for noisedevices's report.
How can it be done?what are the knowledge I need to know before process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `project/report.html.erb`, the `noisedevice/_report.html.erb` view can be called with the render method as follows:

```
<%= render "noisedevice/report", locals: { some_date: some_date, project_id: project_id } %>
```

See [2.2.3 Rendering an Action's Template from Another Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller) at RailsGuides for more detail about calling view of another controller.

And [3.4.4 Passing Local Variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) for details about passing local parameters.

The entire page on that guide is worth going over.

Comment: How to pass date string and project number as parameter to noisedevice controller?this render seems work fine but lack the parameter part~

Comment: Updated answer with the info; refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables for how to pass local variables to views.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters via links like this:

```
<%= link_to new_noisedevice_path({ report_id: @report.id, date: @date })
```

This will generate a get request with the parameters appended to the URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/noisedevices/new?report_id=5&date=xxx
```

You can then grab the parameter like this:

```
@report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
@date = params[:date]
```

Comment: is there a way to do it use a submit_tag?

Comment: how this new_noisedevice_path is formed?following some convention or need modify router.rb and define?